# how to apply numpy vectorized function to ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy ndarray variable:

```py
>>> type(data)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

>> data.shape
(250, 250, 3)
```

It corresponds to a 250*250 image containing black or white pixels.

I would like to convert r,g,b information to boolean value (black or white), hence obtaining a (250, 250) array containing boolean or 0/1 values.

I tied something like the following without success:

```py
iswhite = lambda t: t[0] == 255
vfunc = np.vectorize(iswhite)
vfunc(data)
```

I believe I have to somehow use the parameter `signature` of the `vectorize` function but I could not figure out how to do that despite looking at Numpy documentation.

For info, I know I can achieve what I want with other ways like:

```py
np.alltrue(data == [255, 255, 255], axis = 2)
```

But here I want to learn how to use vectorized functions.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Note that if the goal is to accelerate codes with `np.vectorize`, then this is a waste of time (Numpy cannot truly vectorize Python functions).

Comment: `np.vectorize` is best for functions that only take scalar inputs, and you want to use arrays that broadcast against each other. Even there it isn't a speed tool.  The signature feature is even slower. In this case it will call the function 250*250 times, at python loop speeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you should not see `np.vectorize` as a means to accelerate runtime. Per [the document](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) it is just a fancy `for` loop.

Back to the question of how to use `np.vectorize` in this case, you need to pass `signature` so that `vectorize` knows it needs to work on an array:

```
iswhite = lambda t: (t == 255).all()
vfunc = np.vectorize(iswhite, signature='(n)->()')

vfunc(data).shape
# (250,250)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your lambda function is wrong for what you're trying to achieve (I don't even want to discuss if it makes sense or not). You lambda function should be this:

```py
iswhite = lambda t: 255
```